# Understanding implications of a certain property in an associative ring with unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm delving into a property within an associative ring with a unit element $R$, where the identity $(xy - yx)^{100} = 0$ holds true for all $x, y \in R$.

My inquiry revolves around whether this implies that $(xy - yx)^{99} = 0$ for all $x, y \in R$.

I've attempted to deduce the relationship between $(xy - yx)^{100}$ and $(xy - yx)^{99}$ in the context of an associative ring with a unit, but I'm facing challenges in determining if the property holds for the power of $99$ based on the given property for the power of $100$.

Could someone provide insight, a theorem, or a step-by-step approach to ascertain whether the property $(xy - yx)^{100} = 0$ for all $x, y \in R$ necessarily implies $(xy - yx)^{99} = 0$ for all $x, y \in R$?

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to the well-known commutativity theorems by I. N. Herstein, see his Noncommutative Rings, chapter 3 (say the one which states $(\forall x,y: [x,y]^{n(x,y)} = [x,y]) \Rightarrow \forall x,y: [x,y] = 0$), however here the ring actually need not be commutative. As for an example, take the upper triangular ring $UT_{100}(\Bbb C)$. The commutators are strictly upper triangular matrices, and there are such matrices $M$ that do not have $M^{99} = 0$, e.g. the Jordan block.